macOS Terminal Font settings are reset upon every macOS update
After every macOS update I have to manually import my Terminal Profiles as the Font settings are reset to default. Any Ideas on how to fix this or automate/script Terminal settings?

Are you changing settings in one of the default Apple-supplied profiles or are you creating a new profile with a new name?  I would expect the Apple-supplied profiles to potentially get stepped on, while a user-created profile would not be.  I have been using the same terminal profile for years, across multiple major OS upgrades and countless minor upgrades, and have never had the user-created profile be touched.

You can backup your Terminal settings (including profiles) to a new file and restore them on boot up (I don't know how you could do it only after a software update):
1. Backup
Create a copy of the com.apple.Terminal.plist file (containing Terminal preferences) with (specify the path and name of the new file if needed):
cp ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist ~/Documents/terminal_prefs_backup.plist

2. Restore
To restore your preferences automatically on boot up, you can make an Automator app that runs on startup.
You can create an Automator app that runs the following shell script (adapt path if needed):
cp ~/Documents/terminal_backup.plist ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist

You can then add it as a Login Item in System Settings > General > Login Items so that it runs on boot up.

